is used in the sport of gymnastics for people to move and balance on

beam:
a wooden bar that is used in the sport of gymnastics for people to move and balance on

Source: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beam_1?q=Beam
Is the grammatical construction of the quotation "a wooden bar that is used in the sport of gymnastics and that is used for people to move and balance on" or is it "a wooden bar for people to move and balance on that is used in the sport of gymnastics"?

Prepositional phrases normally come after the noun or verb they modify. So yes it would change grammatically, because in the second sentence "for people to move and balance on" would modify "a wooden bar" and in the first case it modifies "used". Maybe someone can draw a nice diagram.

We can't really parse "used" as a compound verb here. Your first proposed understanding, using "and," isn't technically possible. What we could imagine is setting the "gymnastics" bit off with commas:

a wooden bar that is used, in the sport of gymnastics, for people to move and balance on

This would make it clear that the structure is not just "a wooden bar for," but "a wooden bar that is used for."
For this particular example, it makes no real difference to the meaning of the sentence either way. But we could imagine one in which it would:

A rudder is a device found on most boats for steering

Or, if we wanted to make it even more parallel, "a device that is found on most boats." It doesn't make any sense to say "found for steering"; based on meaning, it's clear that the phrases "found on most boats" and "for steering" both modify "device," but as a series, without overlapping. I'm not sure it matters in the case of "beam," but this is probably the simplest way to read it as well: A wooden bar, which is used in the sport of gymnastics, as a thing for people to move and balance on.

Normallly, there should be a noun phrase after the preposition "on". What is the reason the example phrase is idiomatic and natural even though there is no noun phrase after "on"?

@Englishgood Perhaps you're thinking of the rule that you "shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition?" Reasonable people today agree that this never needed to be a "rule." The implied noun that "on" references is "beam"; people "move and balance on the beam." A similar structure might be something like "Feelings are worth talking about." Avoiding ending the sentence with a preposition might make it more awkward and less impactful, like "It's worthwhile to talk about feelings."
